# Signature of PostgreSQL Installers (sha1, sha256, MD5 etc.)

Tags: postgresql, installation, verify

I cannot find any reference which clearly shows the signatures of an installer of any PostgreSQL tool in order to verify it. Even looking at the official site (https://www.postgresql.org/download)! It feels very strange to me, but I lost at least one hour looking for them and I was not able to find anything!

Does anyone know where to find those signatures (any official sha, md5 etc. will be OK for me), in general? I'd like to find those *before* using any installer!

Comment: Things like https://ftp.postgresql.org/pub/source/v14.1/postgresql-14.1.tar.bz2.sha256 ?

Comment: Yes! Have you any idea of where to find those for a package/installer? For instance the DMG installer for MacOS or the binaries in a tar?

Comment: Things from EDB download over https and are protected from tampering that way.

Comment: I'm not so sure about it like you are. If this was the case, why most sites with "https" still give those signatures?  For instance, if I decide to download MySQL installers, each signature is very easy to spot as soon you go to the download page (https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/mysql/). Of course, there are countless examples of this (good) practice. So, why should postgreSQL be any different?

Comment: One person's "good practice" is another person's mindless cargo cult.  If you don't trust their website for the download, why would you trust it to distribute the signature for the download?  Back when HTTPS and HTTP (or true FTP) links were routinely mixed in the same page, that made some sense.  But it doesn't anymore.

Comment: I've been thinking about it a lot, and ... you are right! It does not make any sense, especially for the reason I was considering (security). Thanks! :-)